# iOS Paypal Braintree: What does it mean to setup up a server?

Tags: ios, heroku, firebase, paypal, braintree

This might be a most basic question, but what does it mean to have a Braintree server? I understand there is some code which needs to run on a server, which means the 'server' has to be always 'on'?

I've stumbled across Heroku, but are there alternatives? Can I use Firebase, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A server is simply any computer that provides data or services to another computer (or mobile device) over a network, such as the Internet. A server runs special software that allows it to process commands and return data sent from requesting applications. Your laptop, desktop, or even Raspberry Pi could be configured to be a server as long as it's connected to a network and is configured to receive and respond to network traffic. See this [page](http://techterms.com/definition/server) for a more thorough explanation.

In the context of the question, a "Braintree server" is any server that has Braintree's server-side API installed on it and is exposed to a network. Services like [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/es/what-is-aws/) or Heroku are considered Platforms as a Service (PaaS). They provide you with remote access to a server that already has a development environment setup for you. You would simply need to install Braintree in your choice of environment. For example, in Node.js the command is as simple as this:

```
npm install braintree
```

Firebase is considered a Backend as a Service (BaaS). It not only manages the physical hardware and dev environment, it also manages data storage and synchronization. It offers a [rich feature set](http://www.cmarix.com/14-Benefits-of-using-Firebase), but can be more complicated to customize.

You could also get started with a very basic cloud option like [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/). This is considered Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS), because you receive access to a blank server which you can then customize to your heart's content. [Create a droplet](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/droplets/new?size=512mb&region=nyc3), install Python, Ruby, Node.js etc, then [install Braintree](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/node) and get coding.

Any of these services will make sure that your server is "always on". I personally recommend DigitalOcean. You will have to do a lot more of your own setup, but you'll learn much more in the process.

Comment: Great answer. @AJGronevelt: Even when you use a BaaS such as Firebase, you'll find that sometimes you need to run a process that you cannot run on a client's device because it needs to have access to secret information. Interacting with a payment gateway is an example of such a process. You'd run this process in a trusted environment, typically called a "server". Especially in the context of Firebase, these can be quite small hardware-wise, because you put them *behind* the database. Also see: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#firebase-appengine-flexible